# Android listview simpleAdapter get the sum of each Row's last column Textview

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

**I have 3 Arrays for Name,Quantity and Price.**

I use Listview to display them out with SimpleAdapter. On top of that, I have 2 buttons in each row which are used to control the Quantity - Plus and Minus Quantity.

**When clicking on the Plus Or Minus button, the quantity will change and the sub-total of that row will be updated as well.**

If quantity = 1, when clicking on the minus button, it will remain 1;

so far all the functions working correctly.

[image]

**Java**

```
int cal_quantity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main8);

List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

final String name[]={"apple","orange","pear"};
final String quantity[]={"1","2","3"};
final String price[]={"5","10","2"};

for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++){
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("name",name[i]);
    map.put("quantity",quantity[i]);
    map.put("price",price[i]);
    aList.add(map);
}

String[] from = {"name","quantity","price"};
int[] to = {R.id.name,R.id.quantity,R.id.price};

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, aList, R.layout.main7, from, to){
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        final TextView tv_quantity=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        final TextView tv_price=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.price);
        final TextView tv_total=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.total);

        final int get_quantity = Integer.parseInt(tv_quantity.getText().toString());
        final double get_price= Double.parseDouble(tv_price.getText().toString());
        final double get_total=get_quantity*get_price;
        tv_total.setText(get_total+"");

        Button minus=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.minus);
        minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cal_quantity=Integer.parseInt(tv_quantity.getText().toString());
                if(cal_quantity!=1){
                    cal_quantity=cal_quantity-1;
                }
                tv_quantity.setText(cal_quantity+"");
                double get_total=cal_quantity*get_price;
                tv_total.setText(get_total+"");
            }
        });

        Button plus=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cal_quantity=Integer.parseInt(tv_quantity.getText().toString());
                cal_quantity=cal_quantity+1;
                tv_quantity.setText(cal_quantity+"");
                double get_total=cal_quantity*get_price;
                tv_total.setText(get_total+"");
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
};

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main8"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.yu.singleton.Main8Activity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Total"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="36sp" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**My question is how to Add the sub-total of each Row and then display it in a Textview (Total) below the Listview**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the quantity to your data source whenever you plus or minus.
Here is the way to save the quantity to your data source and calculate total when minus, you should do the same for plus

```
minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        cal_quantity = Integer.parseInt(tv_quantity.getText().toString());
        if (cal_quantity != 1) {
            cal_quantity = cal_quantity - 1;
        }

        // Save the quantity to your datasource (aList)
        aList.get(position).put("quantity", "" + cal_quantity);

        // Calculate total
        int total = 0;
        Log.d("TAG", "start total = " +total);
        for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++) {
            Log.d("TAG", "at "+i+ " quantity = " +aList.get(i).get("quantity"));
            total += Integer.parseInt(aList.get(i).get("quantity")) * Integer.parseInt(aList.get(i).get("price"));
            Log.d("TAG", "at "+i+ " total = " +total);
        }
        // Display total, currently I use Toast, you can display it into your TextView
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total " + total, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: hey ! thx for ur answer. However, the math calculation is not correct. It only correct for the 1st button click. when clicking 2nd time or more , the math calculation is wrong. any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: @gosulove I have add 2 logcat to my answer, please help me to put it into your code, then run your app again and show me what the logcat displays. thank you

Comment: please check my edited question. I posted there for your reference. thx

Comment: I have add a `Log.d("TAG", "start total = " +total);`. please add it to your code and debug again. make sure you don't put the total variable outside of onClickListener, put it inside like my code

Answer (score 2):

What you have now as total already reflects the sub total of each row item in your listview.

I would recommend shifting your list of hashmap out as an instance variable of the activity so that it has a broader scope, along with that declare another variable to store your total.

Write a method that iterates your list of hashmap and for each iteration, get quantity, get price and multiply them together. Add this value to your total variable in each iteration and once the iterator completes, set the total textview's value to be equal to your total variable. Set the total variable to be equals to 0.0 at the start of this method.

Call this method in the last line of each of your buttons' listener. 
I would however recommend that you do it in an object oriented way in which your list of hashmap can be just a simple list of objects. Helps with clarity.

```
int cal_quantity;
private int total;
**private TextView grandTotal_TV;**

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main8);
**grandTotal_TV = findViewById(R.id.TextView3);**

List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

final String name[]={"apple","orange","pear"};
final String quantity[]={"1","2","3"};
final String price[]={"5","10","2"};

for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++){
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("name",name[i]);
    map.put("quantity",quantity[i]);
    map.put("price",price[i]);
    aList.add(map);
}

String[] from = {"name","quantity","price"};
int[] to = {R.id.name,R.id.quantity,R.id.price};

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, aList, R.layout.main7, from, to){
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        final TextView tv_quantity=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        final TextView tv_price=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.price);
        final TextView tv_total=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.total);

        final int get_quantity = Integer.parseInt(tv_quantity.getText().toString());
        final double get_price= Double.parseDouble(tv_price.getText().toString());
        final double get_total=get_quantity*get_price;
        tv_total.setText(get_total+"");

        Button minus=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.minus);
        minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cal_quantity=Integer.parseInt(tv_quantity.getText().toString());
                if(cal_quantity!=1){
                    cal_quantity=cal_quantity-1;
                }
                tv_quantity.setText(cal_quantity+"");
                double get_total=cal_quantity*get_price;
                tv_total.setText(get_total+"");
                **calculateTotal();**
            }
        });

        Button plus=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cal_quantity=Integer.parseInt(tv_quantity.getText().toString());
                cal_quantity=cal_quantity+1;
                tv_quantity.setText(cal_quantity+"");
                double get_total=cal_quantity*get_price;
                tv_total.setText(get_total+"");
                **calculateTotal();**
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
};

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
**private void calculateTotal()
    {
        total=0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i<aList.size(); i++)
        {
            HashMap<String, String> map =  aList.get(i);
            int qty = Integer.parseInt(map.get("quantity"));
            double price = Double.parseDouble(map.get("price"));
            total+=qty*price;

        }
        grandTotal_TV.setText(total);
    }**
```

Comment: i will give it a try later and see if it works. btw, have you tried it before ?